# How to change class of particular input in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to create function (in angularjs controller)  which add particular class to the parent div of the empty input when clicking on the button. And remove that class when i type something in the input. 
I have a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/fUdLv/
HTML:

```
<div ng-app="authorization">
  <div ng-controller="authCtrl as auth">
    <div ng-class="{'error':auth.needEmail}">
        <input type="text" ng-model="auth.email" ng-keypress="auth.clearEmail()">    
    </div>
    <div ng-class="{'error':auth.needPassword}">
        <input type="password" ng-model="auth.password" ng-keypress="auth.clearPassword()">
    </div>
    <div>
    <button ng-click="auth.signin()">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('authorization', [])
  .controller('authCtrl', function() {
    this.needEmail = false;
    this.needPassword = false;

    this.signin = function pay() {
      if (!this.email){
          this.needEmail = true;
      }
      if (!this.password){
          this.needPassword = true;
      }
    };

    this.clearEmail = function(){
        this.needEmail = false;
    }  
    this.clearPassword = function(){
        this.needPassword = false;
    }  
  });
```

But i'm sure it is very bad code, because i have a particular function for working with particular input.  How can i generalize this function for working on every input (for example, if i would have three or four inputs it is not very smart solution to create function for each of them)

Answer (score 0):

How about use `<form>` and `FormController` to control state?

You probably need to read [this guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) from official site.